# How to shorten a jquery search for a specific class with the closest() method

Tags: jquery

With jQuery, is there a shorter way to write the following?

```
$(this).parent().prev().children('.expand-rss-link').css({border:'solid 1px pink'});
```

The following does not work...

```
$(this).closest('.expand-rss-link').css({border:'solid 1px pink'});
```

does not work.

My HTML source code looks like the following...

```
<div class="career-paths">
  <div class="career-paths-head">
  <h3>Agribusiness</h3>
  <a href="#" class="expand-rss-link">View All</a>
  <hr>
  </div>
  <div id="agribusiness-intern" class="expand-rss-section">
   <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and $(this) represents the `<p>content</p>` area.

thanks for any advice

Comment: give your html structure

Comment: I've seen much longer - why is this so bad? Your structure will definitely help

Comment: That's the shortest way anybody can give you without knowing the HTML structure. Also, why would you expect `.closest()` to work? It finds the closest matching element in the current target's ancestors

Comment: the best I can come up with is `$(this).closest('.career-paths').find('.expand-rss-link').css({border:'solid 1px pink'});`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP thanks for the feedback and the good tip.  I was just curious if there was even a shorter way.  I'll probably stick with what I got if nothing else shows more effect.

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks!  that's the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @blackhawk I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).closest("parent level id in which '.expand-rss-link' come as children " here come ".career-paths" ).find('.expand-rss-link').css({border:'solid 1px pink'});
```

so now code is

```
$(this).closest(".career-paths").find('.expand-rss-link').css({border:'solid 1px pink'});
```

Comment: Thank you, that clears up my understanding on how to properly use closest().  much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
$(this).closest('.career-paths').find('.expand-rss-link').css({border:'solid 1px pink'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead::

```
$(".expand-rss-link", $(this).closest('.career-paths')).css({border:'solid 1px pink'});
```

Hope this will help !!